# Express server console.log Issue : 'address' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: node.js, express

I created a server.js code but then I have a issue:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
 
const db = require('./app/config/db.config.js');
  
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and Resync with { force: true }');
});
 
require('./app/route/data.route.js')(app);
 
// Create a Server
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
 
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
 
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Issue1:

> Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string | AddressInfo'.
> Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string'.

Issue2:

> Property 'port' does not exist on type 'string | AddressInfo'.
> Property 'port' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these approaches

this prints `App listening at http://:::8081`

*if the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.*

```
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('running at http://' + host + ':' + port)
    });
```

Comment: that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try this

```
var port = config.PORT || 8081; // set your port

var server = app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); 
});
```

you can specify host in `db.config.js` like this

```
var config = {
development: {
  HOST: process.env.DB_DEV_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
  USER: process.env.DB_DEV_USER,
  PASSWORD: process.env.DB_DEV_PASSWORD,
  DB: process.env.DB_DEV_NAME,
  DIALECT: process.env.DB_DEV_DIALECT || "postgres"
},
production: {
   HOST: process.env.DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
   USER: process.env.DB_USER,
   PASSWORD: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
   DB: process.env.DB_NAME,
   DIALECT: process.env.DB_DIALECT || "postgres"
},
test: {
  HOST: process.env.DB_TEST_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
  USER: process.env.DB_TEST_USER,
  PASSWORD: process.env.DB_TEST_PASSWORD,
  DB: process.env.DB_TEST_NAME,
  DIALECT: process.env.DB_TEST_DIALECT || "postgres"
}
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thank you Arya for your approach!!